# Best way to initialize an array of strings to pass it to a function

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers

I need to intialize an empty array of strings with fixed size ( 3 by 100 for example), pass it to a function to fill it with data and perform things like strcpy(), strcmp(), memset() on it. After the function is terminated I need to be able to read the data from my main().

What I tried so far:

```
char arrayofstrings[3][100] = {0};
char (*pointer)[3][100] = &arrayofstrings;

function(pointer);
```

Initalizing an (empty?) array of strings and initializing a pointer on the first element.

```
int function (char (*pointer)[3][100])
{
strcpy((*pointer)[i], somepointertostring);
strcmp((*pointer)[i], somepointertostring)
memset((*pointer)[i], 0, strlen((*pointer)[i]));
}
```

Is this a good way to do it? Is there an easier way to do it? Whats up with the brackets around the pointer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C string functions expect a buffer to be null-terminated. Your arrayofstrings allocation happens on the stack. Depending on your compiler it might be initialized to all zeros or might contain garbage.

The simplest way in your case to make sure string functions won't overrun your buffers is to set the first character of each to 0 (null)

```
arrayofstrings[0][0] = 0x00;
arrayofstrings[1][0] = 0x00;
arrayofstrings[2][0] = 0x00;
```

This will give you 3, 100-char buffers that contain a valid empty "string". Note that you can only store 99 "characters" because the last character must be 0x00 (null-terminator).

---

```
char (*pointer)[3][100] = &arrayofstrings;
```

This is unnecessary.

Something to keep in mind about arrays in C is that the [] index is really only there to make things easier for the human programmer. Any array definition is simply a pointer to memory. The values inside the [][]...[] indexes and the type are used by the compiler to allocate the right amount of memory on the stack and do some simple math to come up with the right memory address for the element you want to access.

```
char arrayofstrings[3][100];
```

This will allocate sizeof(char)*3*100 bytes on the stack and give you a char* called 'arrayofstrings'. There's nothing special about the char* itself. It would be the same pointer if you had `char arrayofstrings[300]` or `char arrayofstrings[3][10][10]` or even `long arrayofstrings[75]` (char is 1 byte, long is 4 bytes).

Because you declared it as a multidimensional array with [a][b], when you ask for arrayofstrings[x][y], the compiler will calculate ((x*b)+y)*sizeof(type) and add it to the arrayofstrings pointer to get the address of the value you want. But because it's just a pointer, you can treat it like any other pointer and pass it around or cast it to other types of pointer or do pointer math with it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the extra level of indirection.

An array, when passed to a function, is converted to a pointer to its first member.  So if you declare the function like this:

```
int function(char (*pointer)[100])
```

Or equivalently:

```
int function(char pointer[][100])
```

Or:

```
int function(char pointer[3][100])
```

You can pass the array directly to the function:

```
function(arrayofstrings);
```

Then the body could look something like this:

```
strcpy(pointer[0], "some string");
strcpy(pointer[1], "some other string");
strcpy(pointer[2], "yet another string");
```

Comment: But question is how to initialize, no?  Or maybe it's just unclear.

Answer (score 0):

> Best way to initialize an array of strings ...

`char arrayofstrings[3][100] = {0};` is fine to *initialize* an array of strings.

In C, *initialization* is done only at object definition, like above.

Later code like `strcpy()`, *assigns* data to the array.

---

> Best way to ... pass it to a function

- When the C compiler supports [variable length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), use `function(size_t n, size_t sz, char a[n][sz])`.
- Add error checks.
- Use `size_t` for array sizing and indexing.

---

```
#define somepointertostring "Hello World"

int function(size_t n, size_t sz, char arrayofstrings[n][sz]) {
  if (sz <= strlen(somepointertostring)) {
    return 1;
  }
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    strcpy(arrayofstrings[i], somepointertostring);
    if (strcmp(arrayofstrings[i], somepointertostring)) {
      return 1;
    }
    // Drop this it see something interesting in `foo()`
    memset(arrayofstrings[i], 0, strlen(arrayofstrings[i]));
  }
  return 0;
}

void foo(void) {
  char arrayofstrings[3][100] = {0};
  size_t n = sizeof arrayofstrings / sizeof arrayofstrings[0];
  size_t sz = sizeof arrayofstrings[0];
  if (function(n, sz, arrayofstrings)) {
    puts("Fail");
  } else {
    puts("Success");
    puts(arrayofstrings[0]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Does my initialization initialize the array AND fill it with zeros (thereby making it empty) or does it just initialize the pointers on it? I ask this because in my function I would like to check if the arrayofstrings[][] is empty or already filled with data.

Comment: @Psoke `char arrayofstrings[3][100] = {0};` fills `arrayofstrings` with zeros.  The array in not _empty_.  The ellements are filled with the value 0 - there is no _empty_ state for an array of `char`.  It does not "initialize the pointers on it" as there are no pointers in `arrayofstrings`, just 300 `char`.

Answer (score 0):

> *Initalizing an (empty?) array of strings and initializing a pointer on the first element.*

The type of `&arrayofstrings` is `char (*)[3][100]` i.e. pointer to an object which is a `2D` array of `char` type with dimension `3 x 100`. So, this initialisation

```
char (*pointer)[3][100] = &arrayofstrings;
```

is not initialisation of `pointer` with first element of `arrayofstrings` array but `pointer` will point to whole `2D` array `arrayofstrings`. That why, when accessing the elements using `pointer` you need bracket around it -

```
`(*pointer)[0]` -> first string
`(*pointer)[1]` -> second string and so on..
```

> *Is this a good way to do it? Is there an easier way to do it?*

If you want pointer to first element of array `arrayofstrings` then you can do

```
char (*p)[100] = &arrayofstrings[0];
```

Or

```
char (*p)[100] = arrayofstrings;
```

both `&arrayofstrings[0]` and `arrayofstrings` are equivalent<sup>1)</sup>.

Pass it to a function and access the array:

`function()` function signature should be -

```
int function (char (*pointer)[100])
// if you want the function should be aware of number of rows, add a parameter for it -
// int function (char (*pointer)[100], int rows)
```

this is equivalent to

```
int function (char pointer[][100])
```

and call it in from `main()` function like this -

```
function (p);
```

In the `function()` function you can access array as `p[0], p[1] ...`:

Sample program for demonstration:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ROW 3
#define COL 100

void function (char (*p)[COL]) {
    strcpy (p[0], "string one");
    strcpy (p[1], "string two");
    strcpy (p[2], "string three");
}

int main(void) {
    char arrayofstrings[ROW][COL] = {0};
    char (*pointer)[COL] = &arrayofstrings[0];

    function (pointer);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < ROW; ++i) {
        printf ("%s\n", arrayofstrings[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

1. When you access an array, it is converted to a pointer to first element (there are few [exceptions](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3) to this rule).